# open camera with very small preview window and automatically takes picture- android

Tags: android

I'm working on a application and i want to take the picture of the user automatically with front camera without opening the camera or with a little preview.I can take the picture but the user have to click the button but what I want is it takes picture automatically. I've searched a lot about this but I was unable to get some useful tutorial or code.I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the camera API you can achieve this.

Look at this like http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html

Comment: does this tutorial also shows to how to automatically takes a picture?

Comment: you can write your own timer to do that. so simple.

Comment: I can write a timer but how will i click the button that takes picture? I mean is there any method i can call so that after a couple of seconds camera takes the picture?

Comment: button.performClick() will do that

Comment: At the moment i've just a single button in the app as i'm trying this for this first time. So which button are you exactly talking about? That button launches the camera app.

Comment: the button which one you use to take the picture. For example, if you have Button captureImage to capture the image. you should call captureImage.performClick() to programmatically click it.

Comment: Okay i get it now. Thank you